Visual Studio seems to be ignoring the "C++ Language Standard" selection in project properties
I have just updated a project to VS2022 from VS2013.  I compiled fine with v120 build tools.  I then changed to v143 build tools.
I'm getting a compilation error that only makes sense if the compiler is trying to build using C++17, but I have C++14 selected.
Any thoughts?


I haven't tried this, but did you include functional? A [mre] may help for others to reproduce.

You can also get a flurry of weird errors if you do something like miss adding a comma inside a header file.  Without an MRE we have nothing to chew on.

including functional solved the problem.  What tripped me up here is I have a colleague who is able to compile it without any changes.  It's still a bit of a mystery, but thanks for the help.

I have a colleague who is able to compile it without any changes One thing about the standard library is that there is no rule that any header in the standard library can not include other headers of the standard library. Your colleague may have had a different version / update of the compiler installed which may have included functional from some other header that this code uses.

@Jimbo Your colleague needs to fix their code.  Regardless if it compiled for them, it is faulty in that the appropriate header was not included.  So the real error stems from copying their code -- it isn't your code that is really the root of the problem.

The configuration dialog only says "Active" in one of the drop down boxes. That means that this is not the configuration used to compile the code!

Regarding the dropdown dialog, there is only one platform supported by this project: Win32.  So I don't think that caused a problem.  I have checked with my colleague and we seem to have identical Visual Studio installs and have the exact same solution files.  Still, it compiles for him without the include line.  It's a mystery, but now that we have a fix we have to move on.  Thanks for the help, everyone!

std::unary_function requires header file <functional>.
std::unary_function is deprecated in C++11.(removed in C++17)
